# System Date saved as a 4 digit number in Sqlite database Unity

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

In my Unity game I get the system date and send it to a Sqlite database. But In sqlite database date is save as a 4 digit number.

this is the code I used to get date.

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("date_time", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); 
CurrentDate = PlayerPrefs.GetString("date_time");
```

This is how I insert it to database.

```
//Add new event with o timer at the start of the game
    public void AddEvent(){
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
            dbConnection.Open();

            using(IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
                string sqlQuery = String.Format("INSERT INTO events(date,timer_count) VALUES({0},0)",System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                dbCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                dbConnection.Close();
            }
        }

        PlayerPrefs.SetString("date_time", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); 
        Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("date_time"));
    }
```

This is how date looks like in unity editor when I print it out:
[image]

But this is how it looks like on Sqlite database:
[image]

The number decreases when date is increasing.

> Example: 2018-10-28 => 1982   | 
>            2018-10-29 => 1981

I want to store the date in sqlite database in same format that displayed in Unity editor. (yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: What is 2018 minus 10 minus 28 (sure you're not seeing 1980?) Why aren't you using a placeholder for the date string in your insert statement?

Comment: try this => `string sqlQuery = String.Format("INSERT INTO events(date,timer_count) VALUES({0},0)", System.DateTime.Now.Date);`

Comment: @Shawn Yes, Its "2018 minus 10 minus 28", How can it happen when its converted to string? When I change it to (2018/10/29) it stores 6 in database.

Comment: I changed System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") to System.DateTime.Now.ToString().Substring(0,10) to get just the date. Now it stores 0 in the date field in sqlite database.

Comment: @SNoV, did u try my above commented code statement?

Comment: Yes, It prints both Date and Time.

Comment: @SNoV, so whats the datatype of your `date` column in sqlite table?

Comment: I tried both VARCHAR and TEXT.

Comment: @SNoV, try to add single quotes placeholder like => `VALUES('{0}',0)` in above query

Comment: 2018/10/28 does division just like 2018-10-28 does subtraction. *Don't* try to insert string values directly in a statement at run time; even with ones that won't cause SQL injection attacks there's too many edge cases involving quoting and it's a bad habit to get into. Use prepared statements with placeholders and bind the values to them.

Comment: @ershoaib Adding placeholder like you suggested has worked. Thankyou

Comment: @SNoV, glad to hear, i added the answer you just mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add placeholder to your query like `('{0}')`

```
string sqlQuery = String.Format("INSERT INTO events(date,timer_count) VALUES('{0}',0)", System.DateTime.Now.Date);
```

**Note:** Use prepared statements that can prevent sql injection.